# Sonarqube and the github synchronization with maven

Tags: sonarqube

Can Sonarqube synchronize automatically the created issues of a github repository? I'ld like to use maven to replicate automatically all issues in my github repository. Something as:

mvn install sonar:sonar -D......

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand your use case. Can you detail a bit more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I would that when I generate the issues through sonarqube on a github projects, automatically theese issues are synchronized in the github repository of the project

Comment: You mean: when you analyze a project on your SonarQube, and that the sources of that project are hosted on GitHub, you want that all the issues reported in SonarQube are also pushed in the "Issues" service of GitHub?

Comment: I will put my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Pushiing all issues reported on SonarQube to the Issues service of your GitHub repository is not a good idea:

- You will end up having probably hundreds of issues, thus the bugs, improvements or feature requests will be lost in all that noise
- And this will probably be very complex to handle the synchronization when issues are resolved on SonarQube side

To sum up, this feature is not available and it has little interest (in my opinion).

Comment: thanks for the response. The same thing can be done on a project tracking server, for example jira? https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira

Comment: May it be GitHub Issues, JIRA or whatever bug tracking system, the answer is the same in the end: it does not make sense because issues in SonarQube are too granular.